# Laravel 4, Save forms with Radio buttons

Tags: php, html, database, laravel-4, radio-button

I'm using laravel 4. I'm new and I'm trying to make an online test system, I made the view with questions.

I have already registered users and administrators. I have authenticated the login. I have authenticated any failure to register a user.

I want to know how can I save forms that contain several radio buttons and grade the test automatically.

The result can only be viewed by administrators. The result will not be given to the student.

Each question has 4 radio buttons. My idea is to assign the true answer "1" and 3 missing responses assign "0" in order to save only the correct answer in the database. but I dont know how to do that.

I know I'm asking a lot, but I hope you can tell me how I can do it or put a link where I can base myself to do it. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

create array key => question values => [answers]
in two loops list all the questions with possible answers like

```
{{ Form::checkbox('answer_name', 1, false, ["required"]) }}
```

when user hit the submitt button do the validation stuff,
then get only keys form Form where value is true or 1 nvmd.
use loop where compare model_answer array with user_answer array and if answer is correct iterate some variable to get result.
Remember, position in array counts!